# Refused to connect to 'https://...URL' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'

Tags: javascript, express, server, fetch, google-chrome-devtools

Basically I am trying to send myself some information from https://www.binance.com/.

I am trying to make a fetch request to my express server from the devtools console and I get the following error:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://example.com/movies.json' because it \nviolates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https://bin.bnbstatic.com https://public.bnbstatic.com wss://stream.binance.com wss://nbstream.binance.com wss://haodesk.binance.im https://upload-bnbstatic-com.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com https://*.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com wss://*.binance.com https://*.binance.com https://frontend-m.binance.cloud https://sensors.binance.cloud https://report.binance.gg https://*.sentry.io https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://bin.bnbstatic.com https://resource.bnbstatic.com https://ex.bnbstatic.com wss://stream.binance.com wss://margin-stream.binance.com:9443 undefined undefined wss://bstream.binance.com:9443 https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://*.litix.io https://*.wistia.com https://embedwistia-a.akamaihd.net".
```

And then:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://...URL...' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

And the promise gets rejected.

So I thought it may be some configuration with my server (thought it was cors) so I tried to fetch this dummy url from the devtools console with:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

And I keep getting the same error.

I tried the same in different websites (stackoverflow let's say) and it works.

Is there any workaround to make a fetch request from the devtools console and bypass this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what tab you open. Chrome and other browsers nowadays, if you open a blank tab they would run something. Therefore for safe, if you'd like to run your developer tools and test something, just open https://www.google.com/ , open your developer tool again then type the script again in the console, for example :

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/').then(response => response.json()).then(json => console.log(json));
```

Then it'll work fine. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rPfU.png)

The other way is to open a new tab and type in this :

```
about: blank
```

Then you can run the fetch again, and it works fine.